# Facebook Error: 'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param \"state\" missing from persistent data'

Tags: php, symfony

После авторизации на странице Facebook переходит на указанную страницу сайта, где при попытке получить accessToken приходит ошибка от Facebook: 'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data'.

Домены добавленны в список.

Используется, symfony 3.3 и facebook/graph-sdk 5.4

```
/**
* @Route("/{_locale}/fb-callback", name="fb-callback", defaults={"_locale": "ua"}, requirements={"_locale" : "ua|en|ru"})
* @param Request $request
* @param $_locale
* @return mixed
*/
public function fbCallbackAction(Request $request, $_locale)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => ********,
        'app_secret' => *******,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); // Error
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->logToFile('Facebook returned an error: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        exit;
     }
```

[image: Добавленные домены]

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть объяснили немного то, что тут написано. Какая библиотека используется для работы с facebook api, какая версия, что в вопросе делают теги фреймфорков, которые в самом вопросе не участвуют?

Comment: Спасибо, информацию добавил. Все найденные ответы сводятся к неправильно прописанным  урлам (текущие отображенны на скриншоте) или проблем с сессией (проблем не обнаруженно). Проект давно в работе, но проблема проявилась в течении последнего месяца